# Incomplete execution with join

Tags: java, multithreading, join, concurrency

there is some problem in this code, its not getting executing. but when i am uncommenting the finally block, its just printing the "complete" without printing "holas" , Any idea?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyThread {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static boolean interruptTask=false;

    public static class D extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            while(!interruptTask){
                System.out.print("Hello");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread task = new D();
    task.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    interruptTask=true;
    try {
        task.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }/*finally{
        System.out.println("holas");
    }*/
    System.out.println("complete");
    }

}
```

Comment: That was premature of me, so I've re-opened.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just waiting 5seconds?

Comment: yes, you may also try on eclipse, hopefully you will get same result

Comment: I very much doubt your results. Please turn your `sleep` amount to like `1000`. And put a `sleep` in the `run()` as well so as not to fill up your console buffer.

Comment: this will change the question. :(

Comment: No, `sleep` doesn't affect anything, just the amount of text you'll have in console.

Comment: Even if i am increasing sleep time, i should atleast get "Hello" printed on console by other thread, even i am not getting thats

Comment: That's absolutely not normal. Make sure you are running the code you've pasted.

Comment: ya, thats what i am not getting.

Comment: Even with `volatile`?

Comment: Well, this looks like it might be a genuine issue.  I get the same results, even with `volatile` and even adding a `flush()` call in the loop. However, with `println()` I get the correct output.  More research is needed.

Comment: What java version(and what OS) are you using? I can't reproduce your results(your code works properly for me).

Comment: I'm on 1.7.0_51 in Eclipse Juno (4.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, this is a bug in Eclipse.

When I run the code within Eclipse I get the behavior described by the OP. When I run the generated class file from the command line it works as expected. I suspect Eclipse is buffering the output and "forgetting" to write it out to the console window. The fact that println() works while print() doesn't supports this, but then I would have expected the final println() to cause Eclipse to see the buffer.

I also ran a test where I decreased the timeout from 5000 to 10 (milliseconds), in which case the output is correct in Eclipse.

I suspect an internal buffer in Eclipse, where it stores console output, fills up. My guess is that Eclipse is looking for `\n` to flush to the console window. It never sees this with the OP's original code, and when the buffer fills up Eclipse just discards additional output. Since no `\n` is ever written to the console buffer, it never gets displayed.

I will submit a bug on the Eclipse Bugzilla.  This is a very nice testcase.

EDIT: Here's an even better testcase:

```
public class EclipseBug
{
    private static int count = 781;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            System.out.print("hello ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With `count = 780` it works. With `count = 781` no output is produced.

Eclipse Bug Filed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443433